# Whenever I attempt to copy a large number of files to my external hard drive, a blue-screen of death pops up. Is my hard drive fried?

Tags: bsod, sata

I've been trying to copy a large folder containing hundreds of music files to my external hard drive, which is actually a regular SATA hard-drive inside an enclosure, attached to my laptop via USB.

I've attempted this several times, but whenever I do, somewhere along the line I'll get a blue screen of death and the system will dump memory contents to the hard drive before doing a complete restart.

The enclosure is brand-new, so I assume it wouldn't be the problem.

So that leaves the hard drive, but the hard drive itself is relatively new as well (well, 1 year old, but hasn't been used much.)

So does this mean the hard drive is completely cactus?

Comment: Can you try a different hard drive (that you know works) in the enclosure, to first of all rule out the enclosure as a problem?

Comment: Have you tried copying only a portion of the files at a time?  Does it always BSOD on the same file?

Comment: What OS are you running? This is usually indicative of a USB driver issue. I've seen it on 64-bit Windows.

Comment: @Randolph, Yeah I'm running 64-bit Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're running a 64-bit version of Windows, I can say from experience that your issue is the USB controller's drivers.

Have a look at finding the right drivers on the motherboard manufacturer's website.

The good news is, your drives are probably both fine.

Comment: Best of luck. I had a server that worked fine until I reinstalled. I forgot which drivers I used, and the USB drive has blue-screened every time since. I eventually moved it to a 32-bit machine and backed up over gigabit ethernet.